# Way to handle SVG file elements in Android

Tags: android, svg, android-jetpack-compose, android-library

I have a blueprint of a building like this:

[image]

I want to import this blueprint (in SVG format) in a Android app project inside a drawable folder. This blueprint will be renderized on the device screen.

Each room in the building blueprint, internally in the SVG file, is represented by a tagged element. This way, I could to access programatically each room and to handle this element in different ways. For instance, I could paint one room:

[image]

I know about an app built for iOS platform which it works this way. This app uses a library named [**SVGView**](https://github.com/exyte/SVGView), which makes this possible for iOS developers when they use SwiftUI.

The question: is there any similar way or a library like **SVGView**, but for Android (preferably, for Android Compose), where Android Developers can handle programatically elements of a SVG file?

I have searched some Android libraries, but none of them provide me a way to access any element inside a SVG file (like a node) so I can handle this element the way I want and then to render it on the screen. The Android libraries that I found was:

- [SVG to Compose](https://github.com/DevSrSouza/svg-to-compose)
- [AndroidSVG](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg)
- [svg-android](https://github.com/japgolly/svg-android)